# How to stop double automatic conversion on overflow?

Tags: c, linux, double, long-integer

I have a code in which i am extracting strings from environment using getenv, parsing them into numbers using strtod. 
If user enters, 213.123. Then 213 and 123 will be individually fed to a long type.

`long a1 = 213; long a2 = 123`

**The problem i am facing is, if user enters a very long number like: 123456789123.45678, it is automatically getting rounded off, which i don't want and instead throw an error, however ERANGE isn't working.**

```
9 static  volatile int flag;                   /* flag variable to indicate when the measurement should start */
10 static  time_t       ef_errtrack_start_sec;  /* error track start time in seconds */
11 static  long         ef_errtrack_start_nsec; /* error track start time in nanoseconds */
12 static  time_t       ef_errtrack_end_sec;    /* error track end time in seconds */
13 static  long         ef_errtrack_end_nsec;   /* error track end time in nanoseconds */

21 int main(int argc, char **argv)
22 {
23     extractTime(1); /* Extracting start time */
24     extractTime(0); /* Extracting end time   */
25 
26     printf("start: %12d, %12d\n", ef_errtrack_start_sec, ef_errtrack_start_nsec);
27     printf("end:   %12d, %12d\n", ef_errtrack_end_sec,   ef_errtrack_end_nsec);
28 
29     return 0;
30 }


35 void extractTime(int extractStartTime)
36 {
37         char * charPtr, * numberFormatErr;
38         regex_t re;
39 
40         ( extractStartTime == 1 ) ? ( charPtr = getenv("EF_ERRTRACK_START") ) :
41                 ( charPtr = getenv("EF_ERRTRACK_END") );
42 
43         if ( charPtr == NULL )
44                 return;
45 
46         double envVal = strtod(charPtr, &numberFormatErr);
47 
48         if ( (numberFormatErr == charPtr) || (*numberFormatErr != '\0') ) {
49                 ( extractStartTime == 1 ) ? printf("eFence exited: EF_ERRTRACK_START is not a number\n") :
50                         printf("eFence exited: EF_ERRTRACK_END is not a number\n");
51                 exit(1);
52         }
53         if ( errno == ERANGE )
54         {
55                 ( extractStartTime == 1 ) ? EF_Print("eFence exited: EF_ERRTRACK_START is out of range\n") :
56                         EF_Print("eFence exited: EF_ERRTRACK_END is out of range\n");
57                 exit(1);
58         }
59         else if ( envVal < 0 ) {
60                 ( extractStartTime == 1 ) ? printf("eFence exited: EF_ERRTRACK_START a negative number\n") :
61                         printf("eFence exited: EF_ERRTRACK_END is a negative number\n");
62                 exit(1);
63         }
64 
65         if ( extractStartTime ) {
66                 ef_errtrack_start_sec = envVal;
67                 double nsec = (envVal) - (double)(ef_errtrack_start_sec);
68                 ef_errtrack_start_nsec = (long)(nsec * 1000000000);
69         }
70         else {
71                 ef_errtrack_end_sec = envVal;
72                 double nsec = (envVal) - (double)(ef_errtrack_end_sec);
73                 ef_errtrack_end_nsec = (long) (nsec * 1000000000);
74         }
75 }
```

Here is the output:

```
Output:
/tmp # export EF_ERRTRACK_START=1234567891234.123456789123
/tmp # export EF_ERRTRACK_END=10e2

/tmp/time_related # ./a.out 

start:   2147483647,   2147483647
end:           1000,            0
```

Comment: If you want `long`s, why are you using `strtod` instead of `strtol`?

Comment: Why would this set `ERANGE` - the number you have provided is within the range `DBL_MIN` to `DBL_MAX`?

Comment: @pmg: This is because users will enter as floating point number. I think i had given the example. `export EF_ERRTRACK_START=231.345`

Comment: @Nim: The purpose is, this will be fed to a timespec structure which takes long, and it will be truncated from the double. 213.679 = 213 secs + (0.345 x 10^9 nano seconds)

Comment: @king ... so what? do `strtol` twice ignoring the decimal point.

Comment: @king: is there a difference between `231.345` and `231.000000000000345`?

Comment: @pmg: No we can't because strtol can't parse exponential numbers. What if user enters `export EF_ERRTRACK_START=34e2` your `strtol` fails

Comment: @pmg`231.345 = 231 secs + 0.345 x 10^9 nsecs` and `231.000000000000345 = 231 secs + 000000000000345 x 10^9 nsecs` Hope you understand the point.

Comment: I see your point ... but, according to your rules, `231.345` and `231.000345` represent the same value :)

Comment: @pmg: No, the rule is `secs = 231` `nsecs = 0.345 x 10^9` not `345 x 10^9` hope you can give some solution now after this long discussion :)

Comment: Why don't you use `sscanf` with `%l.%l`? and if it failed, you know that it's in the form `10e2`, then you write `sscanf` with %le%l` and correct the result to the format you want after

Comment: So you're trying to represent dates that lose precision in a double (about 16 significant decimal figures)? You realise that `123456789123.45678` seconds since the epoc isn't for nearly another 4000 years? If you need millisecond or better accuracy out that far, I think you have to give up on `strtod` and roll your own parser for scientific notation.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I have done something simpler, i have used ` if ( ef_errtrack_start_sec >= LONG_MAX || ef_errtrack_start_sec < 0)` and this serves my purpose. May be i will answer my own question after the allowable time of 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

"Outside the range of representable values" means bigger than `DBL_MAX`. Your input is in range, it just isn't exactly representable as a double.

For that matter, `0.1` is also in range, and also isn't exactly representable. Should that also be an error, and if not, what's the difference?

I'm not sure what to advise you to do, because I'm not sure why you consider your case an error. One option would be that once you have your double, convert it back to string with `snprintf` and compare to the original input, see whether they are equal at least as far as the decimal point. That ignores scientific notation, though, so there may be more work required to identify the numbers you don't like.

Edit: ah, initially I didn't really assimilate this: "If user enters, 213.123. Then 213 and 123 will be individually fed to a long type."

Sounds like what you are reading is not a double value, it's two integer values separated by a period character. So don't use `strtod`, find the `.` and then call `strtol` on each side of it.

Comment: The purpose is, this will be fed to a timespec structure which takes long, and it will be truncated from the double. 213.679 = 213 secs + (0.345 x 10^9 nano seconds) and then into a timer. and timespec structure takes arguments of type `time_t` which is long and a `long` value

Comment: We can't directly use strtol as it cannot parse an exponential number

Comment: What i mean is, user can also export as `export EF_ERRTRACK_START=13e2` which strtol cannot parse.

Comment: @kindsmasher1 - I realise that you want to make the user's life easy and flexible - however there are times where it makes sense to enforce some rules - if the expectation here is that the user enter a second/nanosecond value why not enforce a specific pattern - i.e. `"%ld %ld"` - a space separated attribute which has two longs - I think this is fairly reasonable... Else you'll have to do a lot of magic (i.e. checking the string to see if scientific, and then parsing  one way or another - it will be horrible.)

Comment: @Nim: But we have to extract the values from environment variable. IF we had done a scanf, then "%ld %ld" can be done, also we can't restrict the user not to enter a scientific number with `e`

Comment: @kinsmasher1: you also can't stop the user typing "six weeks ago next Tuesday" into that environment variable, but just because the user can type it in doesn't mean you *necessarily* have to accept it and figure out what they mean by it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Exactly, that's why we need to throw errors. And to decide we need to accept or not we need some mechanism, and that's what we are trying to figure out here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to parse the input, identify the possible types (and errors) and act accordingly (no `double` necessary)

```
if input has no '.' and no 'e' then secs = input; nano = 0;
if input has '.' and no 'e' then secs = firstpart; nano = secondpart (scaled appropriately)
if input has no '.' but has 'e' then convert into the 1st or 2nd format above
if input has '.' and 'e' then convert into the 1st or 2nd format above
if input has '.' after 'e' then give error
if input has 2 or more '.' then give error
if input has 2 or more 'e' then give error
... something else I didn't think about
```

Comment: That parsing strtod can do it directly.

Comment: Except that by using the library you have no control over errors. By making your own parser you can control **and bypass** errors in input you consider OK but the library doesn't.

Comment: How?? `strtod` while parsing a scientific number can give errors.

Comment: I meant **rounding** and errors. You control rounding and error within your own parser.